# Statements regarding manual labour in Satya yuga

Tags: scripture, krita-yuga

According to Hanuman, there was no manual labour in Krita yuga.

The following in a excerpt from the discussion between Bhimasena and Hanuman that contains the statement of absence of manual labour during Krita yuga.

> Thereupon Hanuman said, 'O child, that yuga is called Krita when the
>   one eternal religion was extant. And in that best of yugas, every one
>   had religious perfection, and, therefore, there was no need of
>   religious acts. And then virtue knew no deterioration; nor did people
>   decrease. ...... And there was no buying and selling. And the Sama,
>   the Rich, and the Yajus did not exist. **And there was no manual
>   labour**. And then the necessaries of life were obtained only by being
>   thought of. And the only merit was in renouncing the world. And during
>   that yuga, there was neither disease, nor decay of the senses....'
>
> [[Section 148, Tirtha-yatra Parva,  Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03148.htm)

Are there any other scriptural statements that **support** this statement?