# Why jivan mukthas won't do dharma with mental effort only?

Tags: advaita, mukti

This question should be answered based on Advaitha only.

There are many jivan mukthas across scriptures who carried out their profession: Rama, Krishna, Vasishta, Vyasa, Suka, Vishwamitra, Lila, Prahladha, cudala and many others.

It is true that a person who is Jivan muktha is parabrahman herself.

So, she has the faculty of satya samkalpa i.e., whatever she thinks or desires to do will become true.

Suppose a jivan muktha is a queen of a kingdom. Then, she need to perform a lot of tasks such as safeguarding good people, punishing thieves, propagating knowledge etc., for the sake of dharma.

Then why do jivan mukthas, who are continuing in professions, across scriptures won't use the faculty of satya samkalpa without any physical effort for their profession?

As a side note, I want to mention the fact that all [people do their dharmas with mental effort only in Krita yuga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40636/661).

Comment: Wait think slowly and carefully. What is your answer for problem of evil?? God need not wait for someone to become Jeevan Mukta. He can take an avatar and simply stop all suffering. Why doesn't he do it. Because it isn't Dharma. Jeevanmuktas are already doing Dharma. The act of doing it bodily instead of mind is also part of Dharma IMHO, as one is not supposed to disturb the Leela and Samsara. It is part of Dharma. That's why I'm asking what's your answer to problem of evil.

Comment: In so far as my understanding goes, jIvan-mukta is nirguNa brahman. He/she is not saguNa brahman or Ishwara. Only Ishwara or saguNa brahman is the controller of mAyA and only Ishwara possesses unlimited powers. nirguNa brahman has no powers because all powers are meaningful only in the realm of avidyA or mAyA. (A jIvanmukta may have powers due to some other reasons, but none of these powers are comparable to the powers of saguNa brahman).

Comment: I think some questions can only be answered by Jivanmukta person or talking a step ahead, some queries can only be solved after obtaining Jivanmukta realization! Haha